# Using multiple styles in one attributed string

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

```
let myString = text1 + " (\(text2) people added)"
let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue ]
let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)
cell.textLabel?.attributedText = myAttrString
```

How can I use different styles of `text1` and `" (\(text2) people added)"` in one attributed string?

Comment: You can append `NSAttributedString` using the mutable version `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
    var attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
    let str1 = text1
    let str2 = " (\(text2) people added)"
    let attr1 = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
    let attr2 = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: str1, attributes: attr1))
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: str2, attributes: attr2))

    cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attributedText
```